# Paramiko upload file to server

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am uploading files to a server with paramiko. It works perfectly when I am uploading text files, images and scripts however as soon as I try to upload a binary file it throws an `IOError:Failure`.

my code is as follows:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=new_host,port=22,username=user,password=pswd,timeout=3)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.put('/home/pi/file.txt','file.txt')
```

the above code works. As soon as I execute the next command it fails.

```
sftp.put('/home/pi/over','over')
```

this line throws the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):

```
raise IOError(text)
```

IOError: Failure

Comment: Can you upload the binary file using any SFTP (GUI) client?

Comment: Can you try using sftp.open(filename, mode='r', bufsize=-1) method to open 'over' file in your remote server? Verify if your program has permission to create it.
If it is able to then you have problem opening /home/pi/over file in localpath. Checking user, group and access permissions.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl uploading the file works with a previous application that using PLINK and pscftp.

Comment: @harindersingh I have double checked it everything seems fine

Comment: What does Plink have to do with a file upload? + What is pscftp? Do you mean psftp? Show us what were you doing before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it for some reason when the file exists for a text file of the same name and you write to it, it overwrites the file. But for the binary it throws an error can anyone explain?